# Bengali identifiers in java

Tags: java, variables, emacs, initialization

Is it possible to make java treat bengali just like english in java? I mean I want java to print Bengali in "System.out.print(..)" and perfectly understand bengali variable names and initialisation. Whenever I initialise a String variable with a Bengali word, it gives an error.(I am working with converting bengali text to image so I need it).

Comment: Java Strings are based on UTF-8, so yes, you should be able to use bengali. Downside: you might have to write them as `"\uXXXX"` (with `XXXX` being the unicode of the character you want to print)  to get the result you are aiming for.

Comment: @Turing85 : I have an on screen bengali keyboard at hand, is there a way to use bengali just as english, i.e. just typing direct begali letters in java?

Comment: I am not entirely sure on this, but it might help to save your files in UTF-8 format. I have no system with an extended character set at hand to test it myself.

Comment: @Turing85 : Well if you want , there is a bengali keyboard available for free, named the "Avra keyboard" for writing in bengali. You can use it if you want..

Comment: This is not the problem. My OS does not have the character extension installed (and right now, I am not willing to install it). I am quite confident you can test this for yourself.

Comment: *Whenever I initialise a String variable with a Bengali word, it gives an error* be more specific. this is too vague.

Comment: @Turing85 not quite. Java Strings are internally UTF-16 but that is just an implementation details, and are basically just a sequence of unicode characters. Please don't confuse unicode and UTF-*.

Comment: "Whenever I initialise a String variable with a Bengali word, **it gives an error.**". What is the error? --The short answer to your questions is "yes, it is possible" but unless you give us the error message there is no way to tell what is wrong on your side.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt : The error is that it is not being able to recognise the characters used. For example , I executed the code given in the answer by John Coker and it gave 71 errors all of which of the same form: illegal character : '\u00a6' and similar unicode variations

Comment: What IDE do you use? (Or what do you use to edit and compile your code, if you don't use an IDE). It is important that a) your editor uses the same character encoding as your compiler and b) that this encoding supports your script. The typical solution that is supported by most IDEs and standalone editors is to use the UTF-8 encoding for both editor and compiler.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I use emacs as editor in UTF-8 language and Windows powershell is where I write my javac <file>.java     . Can you shed some more light now?

Comment: Change your javac invocation to `javac -encoding utf8 <file>.java`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Well thank you very much and this worked.Now 1 small side question, if you don't mind, (I can post it to form a new question if you want but it doesnot need to I think); In Windows Whenever bengali is "printed"(using("System.out.println), it shows ????????. How can this be modified so that it may display correct bengali?,

Comment: If you're not specifying the encoding for your PrintStream/OutputStreamWriter when you create it (such as when you use System.out) then you need to change the platform default encoding: `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -cp . Example`. However this changes the question marks to empty boxes since the Windows console doesn't support unicode properly. You can direct the application output to a file by appending ` > filename.txt` to the command line, and then open `filename.txt` with an editor that supports UTF-8 and unicode fonts. Or you could use an IDE like Eclipse that supports unicode on its console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java strings are actually UTF-16, but the point is that it definitely will support Bengali characters in string constants.

You can also use alphabetic characters (as well as currency symbols and connecting punctuation) as Java identifiers so it should be possible to use Bengali words as Java identifiers.

```
public class Example {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("উদাহরণ");
       for (int সংখ্যা = 0; সংখ্যা < 10; সংখ্যা++)
           System.out.println(সংখ্যা);
   }
}
```

Comment: This gives a lot of errors saying "illegal characters". Did you use any special java package?

Comment: No, I put that exact text into a file named "Example.java" and compiled and ran it with Java 8.  What type of operating system are you using?

Comment: I use windows windows 7.

Comment: My guess is that your text editor isn't Unicode-aware and perhaps is trying to interpret this UTF-8 web page content as another character set when you paste in the text or when it's saved.  Java itself supports a wide range of characters as identifiers, but most people stick to ASCII for similar reasons.

Comment: I am using emacs as my editor. Now can you throw some more light upon my problem?

Comment: What character set are you using in Emacs?  I use UTF-8 by setting it in my .emacs: (set-language-environment "utf-8")
Note that this isn't a Java question any longer; Java does indeed support the entire range of Unicode characters in strings and more than ASCII characters in identifier names.

Comment: I changed the language environment to UTF-8 but still the error message shows: unmapable character set.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The above code works perfectly well with Emacs. What does `C-x RET f` give you?